# How to export headlines, including subheadings, without other contents in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In the org-mode documentation [regarding export settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html), it describes `arch` as follows.

> Configure export of archived trees. Can be set to **headline** to only process the headline, skipping its contents (org-export-with-archived-trees).

That's almost what I want, but it skips *all* the contents, including the subheadings. I want those subheadings too (without their contents). Take this example:

```
#+OPTIONS: arch:headline

* I want to see this :ARCHIVE:
But not this.
** and also this.
And definitely not this.
```

If I export this file, `I want to see this` is the only thing that comes through. But I was expecting/hoping `and also this` to be exported underneath it as well.

How do I make that happen? I tried adding an extra `:ARCHIVE:` tag to the second level heading, but that does nothing.

Comment: This is kind of the reverse of a similar question that I asked: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings I imagine a very similar answer would also work here, but my elisp skills are close to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the code that I posted [over there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9492/504) can be modified to achieve the behavior you want:

```el
(defun org-remove-contents (backend)
  "Remove contents of headlines with :ARCHIVE: tag."
  (org-map-entries (lambda () 
                     (forward-line)
                     (let ((beg (point)))
                       (outline-next-visible-heading 1)
                       (backward-char)
                       (delete-region beg (point))))
                   "ARCHIVE" tree))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'org-remove-contents)
```

Note that you'll need to set `arch` to `t` in your per-file `#+OPTIONS` for this to work:

```
#+OPTIONS: arch:t
```

Comment: This is a problem for LaTeX which doesn't like empty sections and subsections (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234321/how-to-export-a-document-as-an-empty-skeleton-with-no-content/), but I can work around it. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianZ Huh. LaTeX export works without a hitch on my machine (with `#+OPTIONS: arch:t` and both headlines tagged with `:ARCHIVE:`)...

Comment: Try it with something bigger, so that the output is more than one page. If you export that to a PDF via LaTeX, does it still work for you?

Comment: I got 'org-remove-contents: Symbol’s value as variable is void: tree'. How I can fix this?