# org-mode export headline without contents, if tagged with tag in list

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In [the answer to this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42398/org-mode-export-headline-without-contents), the author posted a function that, in an export, shows only the headline of an entry if the tag is `exportHeadlineOnly`.

It is possible to hide the tags in a list-typed variable that can be customized, like export does with `org-export-exclude-tags` to completely hide some tags, so that one can dynamically decide to hide tags in the current buffer without changing the `~/.emacs` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to modify the condition to read `(when (and org-export-hide-headlineonly (assoc-string 'exportHeadlineOnly (org-element-property :tags el)))`.