# Is it possible in org-mode to export a * heading to a \begin{heading} \end{heading} block construct?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export, tex

I'm trying to export a heading as a block construct.
Something like

```
* heading
  Content
* Another Heading
```

gets exported to

```
\begin{heading}
Content
\end{heading}
\section{Another Heading}
```

Using something like a tag `:block:` or a `:export: block` property for the heading.

I am now using this answer for [is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings) for some of my document which touches on a similar modification which leads me to believe it should be possible.