# How do I export some of the subheadings in a subtree marked as :noexport:?

Tags: org-export

I would like to be able to have an org-mode file that looks like the following:

```
* Some Heading     :ignore:noexport:
** Not exported
   Some stuff.
** Other not exported heading
   More stuff.
** Exported        :export:
   Other stuff.
```

What should get produced when exporting would look like:

```
Exported
--------

Other Stuff.
```

The `:ignore:` tag is used in conjunction with the `ox-extra` package's *ignore-headlines* functionality -- see [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17677/8541) for details.

It seems that the org-mode file above won't currently export -- **is there a workaround that would allow this to work?**  It seems like the key here would be to make org-mode work so that the presence of an `:export:` tag removes any inherited `:noexport:` tag, and vice versa -- the presence of a `:noexport:` tag should remove an inherited `:export:` tag for the headline.

Comment: What level would you want the exported header? As I see it, there might be a problem if it's on the second level, but the first level is not exported.

Comment: Quoting the manual `(info "(org) Export settings")`: "When headlines are selectively exported with `:export:` anywhere in a file, text before the first headline is ignored." In your case, leave out the `:noexport:` tag since the subheadings not tagged with `:export:` will be ignored. Changing the export scope to "Subtree" (with <kbd>C-s</kbd>) will lead to the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to turn off [tag inheritance](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-inheritance.html) to get this behaviour, but it's unclear what would happen to the 'orphaned' heading. You can do this using [local variables](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FileLocalVariables) and setting the `org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance` list.

I don't have access to emacs right now, but the following (untested!) snippet at the start of your org file might do it.

```
 # -*- mode: org-mode; org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance: '("noexport"); -*-
```

Comment: I still want the tag of the nearest parent node to be inherited by its children.  So I could have, e.g., one subtree whose children inherited `:noexport` unless explicitly marked as `:export:`, and other subtrees whose children inherit `:export:` unless explicitly marked as `:noexport:`.

Comment: So you want to keep tag inheritance but have the child tag overwrite the meaning of the parent tag? That could be tricky.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like, but I realize it would need to be determined what the export behavior should look like if the parent were *not* an `:ignore:` node but had a `:noexport:` tag, and some of its ancestors had `:export:` tags -- maybe this reversing-of-the-inherited-tag behavior only makes sense to allow for `:ignore:` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I find it difficult to understand why would want to export a subheading and not export the heading associated to it. But if you have good reasons for doing so may be you can request this feature on the org-mailing list? The option might be add in future releases?

I usually to something like the following

```
* Some Heading     
** Not exported     :ignore:noexport:
   Some stuff.
** Other not exported heading     :ignore:noexport:
   More stuff.
** Exported        :export:
   Other stuff.
```