# Omitting headlines when exporting from org mode to LaTeX

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Org mode headlines are turned into `section{...}`,
`subsection{...}`, &c. when exported to LaTeX.  How can I ignore
them instead, making the org structure invisible in the exported
document? (preferably allowing normal behaviour only when a
certain tag (:head:) is present, but I would rather disable 
automatic sectioning altogether than keep the default behaviour.)

Comment: See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings

Comment: @artscan, thanks, I saw this before, but can't find the package ox-extra.  Also, this answer allows exclusion of tagged headlines, but I want exclusion by default and inclusion only of tagged headlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org-plus-contrib` package and org-mode git repo contain `ox-extra.el`. You can extend its functionality (see https://github.com/boykov/org-mode/compare/ox-extra-notignore) and use `notignore-headlines` with *:notignore:* tag instead of `ignore-headlines` with *:ignore:* tag.

Comment: This works -- thanks! -- but it would be best if the :notignore: tag were invisible in the exported document.

Comment: If you do not need tags in exported files, you can use `#+OPTIONS: tags:nil`, but it works for every possible tag.

Answer (score 0):

As of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52460/how-can-numbering-of-specific-headings-be-disabled-in-org-modes-latex-export, you can set the property `UNNUMBERED: t` to translate a specific section to `section*` instead of `section`:

> ```
> * numbered
> ** subnumbered
> * unnumbered
> :PROPERTIES:
> :UNNUMBERED: t
> :END:
> ```