# orgmode export - skip/ignore first headline level

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In orgmode, is there an easy way to tell the exporter to ignore the first heading level and start exporting at the second level? I imagine something like this:

in org:

```
* Toplevel
** Head_1
  content 1
** Head_2
  content 2
** Head_3
  content 3
```

to be exported to:

```
1. Head_1
  content 1
2. Head_2
  content 2
3. Head_3
  content 3
```

Thanks for your help!

** **Update** **

After the comment by @artscan I revisited the :ignore: tag, and it indeed achieves what I need. To use it you need to add to the .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/orgdir/contrib/lisp" t)
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

Please note that this also requires org-mode 8.3+

Once ox-extra is installed, simply tag the *Toplevel headline with :ignore:

Comment: You can attain similar behaviour with `ignore` tag, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17677/2064

Comment: Thanks @artscan, it worked. I updated my original question with the solution. I had tried :ignore: before, but it simply wasn't installed properly.