# How to avoid export org-mode header title

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

I am translating a quite flat document (only has a title as a level 1 heading). I am using org-mode and I am creating a level 2 heading for each page to easily find the content when I am reviewing the translation which makes the process easier.

I wonder if there is a way to export the full document to PDF/HTML and not include the level 2 headings TITLE but indeed include the full content within the level 2 heading. I need to ingore only level 2 heading titles.

Thanks.

Herewith an example:

```
* The document title

** DONE Pag 1

bla bla...

** TODO Pag 2

...more bla bla...
```

Desired output:

```
* The document title

bla bla...

(new page)

...more bla bla...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ignore` tag and `clearpage` property to `t`.

```
** Heading              :ignore:           
:PROPERTIES:
:clearpage: t
:END:

This will be exported on new page w/o heading.
```

The `:ignore:` tag is enabled with:

```
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

Source: [Is it possible to export content of subtrees without their headings?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings)

Comment: Surely, this requires some setup: AFAIK, an `ignore` tag is not special. Am I wrong?

Comment: I couldn't make it to work as you explained. The heading 2 text does not appear as a heading 2 any longer, but it is still there as regular text. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added config details for `:ignore:` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.